# modifying xml using groovy (JenkinsFile)

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy

I have a **context.xml** file. The content of **context.xml** is as given below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Manager className="com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.sessionmanager.DynamoDBSessionManager"
        awsAccessKey=""
        awsSecretKey=""
        table="MyTable"
        regionId="us-east-1"
        createIfNotExist="true" />
</Context>
```

Using JenkinsFile (groovy) I need to add the values to **awsAccessKey** and **awsSecretKey**, and updates to **context.xml**

Can we use normal groovy code in Jenkinsfile for file operations?

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: what is it: `Jenkinsfile` ?

Comment: @daggett its a [JenkinsFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) used for Jenkins Job

Comment: are you using jenkins-pipeline?

Comment: @daggett yes..........

Answer (score 3):

You can use Groovy's `XmlSlurper` for that and just change the content of the property after parsing and then re-serialize it back to the file, like this:

```
def slurper = new groovy.util.XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlOriginal)
slurper.Manager.@awsAccessKey = "Meow"
slurper.Manager.@awsSecretKey = "Woof"
def xmlModified = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(slurper)
new File("context.xml") << xmlModified
```